# Maximizing the interior angles of a triangle on the Earth

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, curated-data, code-request, geodesy

Gauss once surveyed a triangle in the Harz mountains formed by Inselberg, Brocken, and Hoher Hagen to check if the sum of the interior angles really added up to $\pi$ radians. With the precision available to him, they did.

I wonder: which triangle on Earth can be surveyed from the surface to maximize the sum of its interior angles? Mathematica has geographical data at the ready, so perhaps it is within its capabilities to write a function that checks whether there is a line-of-sight between two points.

The way I would start would be by taking one vertex to be a mountain summit with equal prominence and elevation and scanning over visible points on the horizon that are also visible to one another, maximizing the sum of the angles formed. But I am not familiar enough with the geographical data to know how to do the requisite calculations.

Comment: "to check if the sum of the interior angles really added up to π radians" - that this was Gauss's goal is debated (see [here](https://thatsmaths.com/2014/07/10/gausss-great-triangle-and-the-shape-of-space/) and [here](https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s8-06/8-06.htm)). It's more likely that he did it to check the internal consistency of his triangulation measurements. He knew and calculated the expected discrepancy between surface measurements (spherical triangles) and the great triangle encompassing them. He found that his measurements were within that discrepancy.

Comment: Whatever was his final cause it is not debated that he pursued it by checking whether the sum of the interior angles of the triangle he measured really added up to $\pi$ radians.